# gogo/protobuf avoid allocating new objects for repeated field

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc

Consider a simple protobuf file:

```golang
syntax = "proto3";
package tutorial;

import "github.com/gogo/protobuf@v1.3.2/gogoproto/gogo.proto";

message Point {
  uint32 timestamp = 1;
  double value = 2;
}

message Metric {
  string metric = 1;
  repeated Point points = 2 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
}
```

I have compiled the proto to Go using https://github.com/gogo/protobuf

The `gogoproto.nullable` helps generate the `Point` slice as non pointers (pointers will make garbage collector work more):

```golang
type Metric struct {
    Metric               string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=metric,proto3" json:"metric,omitempty"`
    Points               []Point  `protobuf:"bytes,2,rep,name=points,proto3" json:"points"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}
```

However the generated `Unmarshal` function is allocating new objects all the time and appending to the slice.

```golang
m.Points = append(m.Points, Point{})
```

These small allocations are heavy and affect performance. I would like to reuse the same memory and avoid allocations all together, maybe using a fixed length array? Can this be done and how?

Comment: Please specify the least executable example. What means "the same memory"? The same as what?

Answer (score 0):

```
m.Points = append(m.Points, Point{})
```

There is no heap allocations in this code (assuming `m.Points` has sufficient capacity). `Point{}` allocates an object on the stack, and copies it by value into the slice.

Comment: It is the protobuf engine that allocates `m.Points`. The size is of course unknown since you are reading protos, therefore this dynamic array will have to resize and that will reallocate. I want to use a fixed size array, let's say I know I have at most 1k points.